# Odd behavior on RabbitMQ node

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

I'm experiencing some odd behavior in a RabbitMQ 3.6.5 cluster that I set up.

I have 4 nodes and each of them have experienced multiple network partitions. From reading the documentation I can see that the network partitioning is triggered whenever connection was lost between 2 nodes, while they both keep running. I figured this was happening because the machines were trying to sleep every 30 min. I did not get to test that yet.

My current issue is that some nodes refuse to stop.

- on `rabbitmqctl stop` and `rabbitmqctl reset` the cmd freezes/hangs for indefinite amount of time until I cancel the batch command.
- on `rabbitmqctl start_app` I get the the erlang error `error:stop`. I have not managed to figure out what this means.
- on `rabbitmq-plugin enable rabbitmq_management` I get the erlang error `error:noproc` and this appears to come from the fact that while I can not stop the node, there is no actual proccess running.

When I run `rabbitmqctl status` I get the following output:

```
 C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.5\sbin>rabbitmqctl status
Status of node 'rabbit@nc-mso-test04' ...
[{pid,8416},
 {running_applications,[{compiler,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","7.0.2"},
                        {os_mon,"CPO  CXC 138 46","2.4.1"},
                        {amqp_client,"RabbitMQ AMQP Client","3.6.5"},
                        {inets,"INETS  CXC 138 49","6.3.3"},
                        {syntax_tools,"Syntax tools","2.1"},
                        {asn1,"The Erlang ASN1 compiler version 4.0.4",
                              "4.0.4"},
                        {rabbit_common,[],"3.6.5"},
                        {mnesia,"MNESIA  CXC 138 12","4.14.1"},
                        {xmerl,"XML parser","1.3.12"},
                        {ranch,"Socket acceptor pool for TCP protocols.",
                               "1.2.1"},
                        {sasl,"SASL  CXC 138 11","3.0.1"},
                        {stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","3.1"},
                        {kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","5.1"}]},
 {os,{win32,nt}},
 {erlang_version,"Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.1] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:64]\n"},
 {memory,[{total,63018240},
          {connection_readers,0},
          {connection_writers,0},
          {connection_channels,0},
          {connection_other,2736},
          {queue_procs,0},
          {queue_slave_procs,0},
          {plugins,0},
          {other_proc,25970040},
          {mnesia,72168},
          {mgmt_db,0},
          {msg_index,0},
          {other_ets,1522608},
          {binary,92080},
          {code,24836283},
          {atom,1033401},
          {other_system,9488924}]},
 {alarms,[]},
 {listeners,[]},
 {vm_memory_high_watermark,0.4},
 {vm_memory_limit,3401855795},
 {disk_free_limit,50000000},
 {disk_free,281661607936},
 {file_descriptors,[{total_limit,8092},
                    {total_used,0},
                    {sockets_limit,7280},
                    {sockets_used,0}]},
 {processes,[{limit,1048576},{used,107}]},
 {run_queue,0},
 {uptime,771157},
 {kernel,{net_ticktime,60}}]
```

And when I do `rabbitmqctl cluster_status` I get :

```
C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.5\sbin>rabbitmqctl cluster_status
Cluster status of node 'rabbit@nc-mso-test04' ...
[{nodes,[{disc,['rabbit@iol-laptop','rabbit@nc-mso-test01',
                'rabbit@nc-mso-test02','rabbit@nc-mso-test03',
                'rabbit@nc-mso-test04']}]},
 {running_nodes,['rabbit@nc-mso-test01','rabbit@nc-mso-test04']},
 {cluster_name,<<"rabbit@nc-mso-test04.novicell.dk">>},
 {partitions,[]},
 {alarms,[{'rabbit@nc-mso-test01',[]},{'rabbit@nc-mso-test04',[]}]}]
```

I tried to forcibly stop the process, deleted the Mnesia database but it did not help.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same situation after playing around with rabbitmq clusters and the following steps helped me:

- stop rabbitmq-service
- remove stuck node's files physically from the file system (in your current user folder on Windows -
  %HOMEDRIVE%\%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ)
- run rabbitmq-service
- install the necessary plugins and reconfigure the node (user, virtual host, etc.)
- run rabbitmqctl start_app